# gawk FPAT doesn't override FS

Tags: shell, awk, gawk

I have a csv file with the format  :

```
"a b c","d","e","f",
"bla","bla","bli","fff"
```

The FPAT as given [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html#Splitting-By-Content) by the official GNU site stipulate that "Assigning a value to FPAT overrides field splitting with FS and with FIELDWIDTHS."
However, I have tried their code  :

```
BEGIN {
    FPAT = "([^,]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")"
}

{
    print "NF = ", NF
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
    printf("$%d = <%s>\n", i, $i)
    }
}
```

with this :

```
echo 'Robbins,Arnold,"1234 A Pretty Street, NE",MyTown,MyState,12345-6789,USA' | gawk -f bin/test.awk
```

and here is the not expected result :

```
NF =  5
$1 = <Robbins,Arnold,"1234>
$2 = <A>
$3 = <Pretty>
$4 = <Street,>
$5 = <NE",MyTown,MyState,12345-6789,USA>
```

I think the default FS (space) was not overriden.
Any idea please ?

Comment: `FPAT` requires gawk version 4. What do you get from `gawk --version`?

Comment: GNU Awk 3.1.7. So that's the reason! Thank you @jas

Comment: Here is the features history of gawk for those interested : https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Feature-History.html

Comment: On the bright side, with 3.1.7 you still have support for Atari :-)

Comment: :-) . I hate theses limitations when you're not working on your own environment. You have to work around it while the solution is on 1 line of code in the next updates!.

Comment: Thanks for this comment stream. All the other pages I found on this topic talked about FPAT as if it was in all versions of awk. Once I knew this was a gawk-specific feature, well, THAT was an easy fix.

Comment: What was the work around with 3.1.7??

Comment: Sorry Sam, I read your comment late. It was a specific bash dev. I quit the old job, so if I find the code, I will post the workaround